# There is a way to block return back to previous page after logout?

Tags: django, django-registration

I am using my own authentification because i don't know how to extend django registration app to make me have a model user where user will have his login and password inside the model. when i logout i and click on the background firefox button i get the other page, when i refresh the page i have an session key error what is normal, i want to solve the problem like in the django admin where you can't go back after logout

```
class User(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    pwd = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created = models.DateTimeField(_('created'), auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def logout(request):
        from django.shortcuts import redirect

        for key in list(request.session.keys()):
            if key == 'id' :
                del request.session['id']
            if key == 'code':    
                del request.session['code']
            if key == 'name':
                del request.session['name']  

    return redirect('/')
```

Comment: You will have to check in each view if the user is logged or not before trying to get the user from session. You could do `'id' not in request.session`.

Comment: just the error key message appear,in the django admin after logging out, if you want to go back, you will stay on the authentification page

Answer (score 0):

It is no way to block a user to go back to the last url, what you can do is redirect the user if it is not logged.

Something like this will do the work:

```
def view(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        redirect('log_in_page')

    # Logged user code
```